# Windows 10 Hello Recognizes but requires pin

Tags: windows, windows-hello

My Spectre has Windows Hello. It recognizes me, but it occassionaly asks me to enter my PIN - something like it needs a pin setup, but I do have one setup.

What steps can I take to remedy this to make it more reliable?

Comment: If it's asking for a pin it means Windows Hello authentication failed, you can either setup a pin so you have one, or switch to password mode and enter that.

Comment: @Ramhound I have a pin set up. the message is to the effect that there isn't one.

Comment: You set the pin again.